# Curiosidade sobre igualdade de Integers

Tags: java, inteiros

Por que

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("0")==Integer.valueOf("0"));
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("1000")==Integer.valueOf("1000"));
```

retorna

```
true
false
```

?

ps. eu sei que `==` é diferente de `equals()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Porque a classe `Integer` faz cache dos valores entre -128 e 127.

Olhe isso:

```java
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("-129") == Integer.valueOf("-129")); // Dá false.
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("-128") == Integer.valueOf("-128")); // Dá true.
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("127") == Integer.valueOf("127")); // Dá true.
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("128") == Integer.valueOf("128")); // Dá false.
```

Eis aqui [alguns trechos do código fonte da classe `Integer`, tal como implementado na OpenJDK](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html):

```java
private static class IntegerCache {
    static final int low = -128;
    static final int high;
    static final Integer cache[];

    static {
        // high value may be configured by property
        int h = 127;
        String integerCacheHighPropValue =
            sun.misc.VM.getSavedProperty("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
        if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
            int i = parseInt(integerCacheHighPropValue);
            i = Math.max(i, 127);
            // Maximum array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
            h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - (-low));
        }
        high = h;

        cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
        int j = low;
        for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
            cache[k] = new Integer(j++);
    }

    private IntegerCache() {}
}

public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}

public static Integer valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s, 10));
}
```

Comment: A explicação está correta. Porém, não se atenha a este código fonte da classe Integer pois não é o código da Oracle que está na JVM padrão. É o código da openjdk, que pode ou não ser igual à implementação original.

Comment: @pablosaraiva Obrigado pela dica. Já atualizei o texto para esclarecer este ponto.

Comment: Lembrando que há como manipular o tamanho desse cache.

Answer (score 3):

Isso é porque a Classe Integer usa o padrão de projeto FlyWeight.

A classe Integer cria um objeto Singleton imutável para cada um dos números de -128 a 127 para que assim esses objetos possam ser compartilhados por toda a aplicação gerando economia de memória.