# É ideal usar tipos primitivos em Java?

Tags: java, tipagem

O Java possui vários *wrapper's* que nos ajudam (`Integer`, `Double`, `BigDecimal`), e também nos dá a possibilidade de usar tipos primitivos (`int`, `float`, `char`).

Um professor disse à minha turma de faculdade que Java não deveria ter suporte a tipos primitivos de dados, tanto que a partir do Java 9 ficarão obsoletos (O professor disse, não sei se é verdade). Isso é fato? Por que não devo usar tipos primitivos nem mesmo em um laço de repetição?

Comment: Estranho, o que sempre ouço falar é que os primitivos, quando estes atendem a ocasião, são melhores para ser usados do que classes wrappers. Vou aguardar um esclarecimento sobre isso também. Boa pergunta +1

Comment: @diegofm sim já vi muitas discussões sobre o assunto, mas nunca ouvi uma explicação sobre se devo ou não usar, isso me deixa muito em dúvida.

Comment: Você editou a pergunta e complicou minha resposta, mas vou dar uma atualizada.

Comment: Editei apenas a explicação o contexto e a pergunta está idêntica.

Comment: `tanto que a partir do *Java 9* ficaram depreciados *(O professor disse, não sei se é verdade '~')` essa parte não tinha na original. Adicionei agora na resposta.

Comment: Desculpe, eu lembrei depois que ele tinha dito isso, achei interessante para complementar a pergunta.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold Agora que já se passaram alguns dias, o que o seu professor disse depois disso?

Comment: @VictorStafusa tive as provas finais nessa época e não consegui abordá-lo para reaver o assunto, tentarei falar com ele na minha colação de grau em fevereiro, ou por meio de facebook, porém essa é uma conversa que prefiro ter pessoalmente ^^

Comment: Um ano se passou, o Java 9 foi lançado, e os tipos primitivos estão aí firmes e fortes. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ele pode ter a opinião que quiser. Ele falou o por quê? Sempre tente entender o porquê, mais do que entender o que. Se ele discorda do que todo mundo faz ele deveria justificar. Algumas pessoas podem achar que é [otimização prematura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101), mas acho muito academicismo achar isso.

- Os chamados tipos primitivos possuem melhor performance. Os tipos não primitivos são referências, possuem indireção no acesso (esse conceito muda um pouco com versões mais novas do Java). A diferença de performance é enorme. Faça um teste de laço com os dois.
- Possuem uma semântica esperada pela maioria das pessoas de que seu valor possui identidade própria e nem sempre fazem o que as pessoas estão acostumadas. Uma cópia não cria nova identidade.

  ```
  Integer x = 1000;
  Integer y = 1000;
  x == y //dá falso já que as identidades são diferentes apesar dos valores serem iguais
  ```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Identity.java).

- Os tipos "não primitivos" alocam espaço no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) e coloca pressão no coletor de lixo. Os primitivos alocam na *stack* e o gerenciamento é simples e rápido. Inclusive desperdiçam muita memória por causa do *overhead* natural que objetos possuem. Novamente isso mudou um pouco em alguns casos.
- Os tipos primitivos não terão problemas de `NullPointerException`.
- No caso específico do Java a sintaxe dos tipos primitivos é mais conveniente do que os tipos não primitivos. Os tipos primitivos não precisam usar `equals()`, por exemplo, mas isso pode estar mudando, pelo menos em parte.

Tem outros problemas em não usar tipos primitivos que não estou lembrando. Provavelmente o uso de não primitivos dificultam a resolução de escolha de *overload* de métodos.

Então é ideal sim, sempre que possível. Inclusive C# possui uma forma de criar tipos por valor próprios - que são os primitivos - e Java tem proposta para ter o mesmo nas próximas duas versões (se já não foi implementado quando ler isso), de tão útil que é. E dará confusão quando isto acontecer, porque o termo ficará ambíguo dentro do que Java sempre usou e algumas das coisas que eu disse aqui nem serão 100% verdadeiras mais, não mudará o fato, mas a definição (por isso eu tive que editar para dizer que algumas coisas mudaram).

Use a forma [encaixotada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55147/101) apenas quando houver um motivo para isso.

Algumas pessoas gostam de pensar de forma linear, outras são mais pragmáticas e escolhem a melhor ferramenta para o trabalho.

Se ele deu ou der uma justificativa posta aqui pra gente.

## Descontinuação

Isso não tem o menor cabimento. Não sei se está expressando algo diferente do que ele realmente disse, mas se isso ocorresse praticamente 100% dos códigos escritos em Java parariam de funcionar. E sinceramente, uma afirmação dessas coloca em cheque a credibilidade da pessoa.

Não só não existe a proposta de descontinuar esse recurso da linguagem, como cogitar isso seria um completo absurdo. Ao contrário, conforme eu já disse, eles devem ser ampliados em versão futura (estava previsto no Java 10, mas mudou tudo no esquema de versões, quem sabe na 15) e você poderá criar seus próprios tipos por valor que são os tipos primitivos. [Veja a proposta oficial](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169).

Veja mais em [O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou procurá-lo e perguntar uma justificativa.

Comment: Acredito que ele tenha se confundido com o termo depreciar, é um excelente professor e entende muito bem, talvez não estivesse em um bom dia :/

Comment: Ou você pode ter entendido um pouco diferente do que ele falou? :)

Comment: Não o termo usado foi depreciado.

Comment: Mas ele pode ter usado em outro contexto, ele pode ter falado de alguma coisa específica e não de todo o conceito de tipo primitivo.

Comment: É possível, de qualquer forma, voltarei a tocar no assunto com ele.

Comment: @bigown a questão de uma versão do java não ter recursos compatíveis com anteriores não seria uma grande surpresa.

Comment: @pmargreff até entendo, mas isso inviabilizaria todas as aplicações, exceto um Hello World :)

Answer (score 20):

As características novas que foram adicionadas ao Java 9 são:

- Jshell - Um interpretador de comandos Java.
- Javadoc com HTML 5 e busca utilizando jQuery.
- Simplificação da compilação cruzada (*cross-compiling*) para versões mais antigas no compilador.
- Anotação `@Deprecated` melhorada.
- Melhorias no controle de processos do sistema operacional (por exemplo: suporte a *kill*).
- `StackWalker` para inspecionar a pilha de execução.
- Fábricas de coleções imutáveis.
- Cliente HTTP2 com websocket.
- Nova modularização com a introdução do conceito de módulos acima do de pacotes.
- Melhorias no locking.
- Arquivos de propriedades UTF-8.
- Implementação do protocolo de transporte DTLS.
- Unicode 7 e 8, incluindo suporte a vários novos emojis.
- Descontinuação das `Applet`s.
- Logging unificado da JVM.
- Suporte a imagens TIFF já incluído por padrão.
- Compilação *ahead-of-time*.
- Strings compactas. [No Java 9, as Strings usam internamente um array de `byte` (primitivos)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/2bf254421854/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l138), ao invés de um array de `char`.
- Método privados em interfaces.
- Várias outras mudanças mais internas e obscuras.

Veja [aqui](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) a lista completa de features.

Em nenhum momento, ninguém falou sobre a possibilidade de se remover os tipos primitivos.

Inclusive, veja [aqui no código-fonte da classe `Integer`, do Java 9, na linha 1101](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/2bf254421854/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l1101) que a classe `Integer` é implementada por meio de um objeto que contém um campo `final` do tipo `int`. Isso é assim desde os primórdios do Java quando ela ainda era chamada de Oak e não mudou até agora.

Além disso, se `int` estivesse descontinuado, então porque que [o método `int parseInt(String)`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/2bf254421854/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l795) não foi descontinuado também? A resposta é porque `int` não está descontinuado coisa nenhuma.

O que foi descontinuado sim foi [o construtor de `Integer` que recebe um `int` como parâmetro](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/2bf254421854/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l1115). O motivo é que usar tal construtor é uma má prática de programação. O recomendável é usar o método `Integer.valueOf(int)`. Casos análogos nas demais classes empacotadoras também ocorrem.

Há sim uma coisa **interna** na JVM onde ela consegue otimizar e simplificar alguns casos em que classes empacotadoras são usadas e transformá-las para uso de tipos primitivos. Com isso, a diferença entre a utilização de classes empacotadoras e primitivos diminui. Mas partir disso para dizer que os tipos primitivos ficarão obsoletos é bobagem.

Comment: Estive a ver o link que você refere como [lista completa de features](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) e não encontrei nenhuma referência a "Método privados em interfaces". Onde posso encontrá-la?

Comment: @ramaral É uma das coisas do *Milling Project Coin*, da JEP 213: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/213 - Veja aqui a *feature request*: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071453

Answer (score 13):

Uma outra razão importante que deve ser levada em consideração ao utilizar ou não os *boxed types (`Integer`, `Float`, etc)*, também conhecidos por *Wrappers*, é que suas classes são imutáveis (assim como a classe `String`). Isso significa que será instanciando um novo objeto para qualquer alteração de conteúdo que a variável sofrer (*exceto para inteiros na faixa -128 a 127, ver final da resposta*).  Assim, se você fizer isso:

```
Integer i = 0;    
i++;
```

Então um novo objeto do tipo `Integer` será instanciado (quando você fizer `i++`), da mesma forma que ocorre com qualquer `String` quando você muda o conteúdo da variável. Portanto, o código acima é muito mais lento do que fazer o mesmo com um tipo primitivo.

Uma outra maneira de ver este problema da imutabilidade aplicada nesse contexto:

Execute o código abaixo:

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) ;
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);
```

Depois execute esse:

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) ;
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);
```

Note que a diferença de tempo é abismal.

Os *boxed types* não foram introduzidos para substituir os tipos primitivos, eles foram introduzidos como um mecanismo para facilitar que tipos primitivos sejam passados como parâmetro onde se espera sua classe correspondente. Um exemplo clássico é quando precisa-se adicionar um `int` em uma `Collection` de `Integer`.

@VictorStafusa fez uma observação importante. Caso o inteiro esteja na faixa entre -128 a 127, então uma nova instância não será criada, pois o Java faz cache para instâncias `Integer` nesse intervalo. Ver essa reposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3381/3084

Comment: "*Isso significa que será instanciando um novo objeto para qualquer alteração de conteúdo que a variável sofrer.*" - Isso é uma meia-verdade. O java mantém uma cache para instâncias de `Integer` que por padrão vai dos números de -128 até 127. Veja mais nessa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3381/132

Comment: Obrigado @VictorStafusa! Já atualizei a minha resposta.

Comment: Excelente resposta!