# As classes wrappers foram depreciadas no Java?

Tags: java, tipagem

Estou seguindo uma sequencia de videoaulas antigas, no vídeo, é usado o Java 7 e o seguinte código compila:

```
Long var3 = new Long("100");
```

Tentei compilar e recebi a seguinte menssagem:

> ```
> Note: Wrappers.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note:
> Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe não aconteceu, nem faria sentido, quase todos os códigos que não fazem coisas triviais usam essas classes. Mas alguns métodos dessas classes agora são considerados obsoletos e devem usar outra forma, no seu caso é um construtor e deve usar [`valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-long-) no lugar que é um método fábrica estático da classe (não gosto muito porque esconde a alocação que antes estava explícita, mas quem programa em Java não costuma ligar pra isso, depois reclama de ineficiência).

Pode ajudar porque não é o primeiro que faz esta confusão: [É ideal usar tipos primitivos em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/101).

Comment: "Esconde a alocação que antes era explícita". Bem, com o `new` ele **sempre** criava um novo objeto. Por exemplo, `for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++) { Long l = new Long(10L); }` vai criar 100 instâncias de objetos idênticos. Então, como essa era uma prática que abusavam do mal uso, preferiram lançar esse alerta. Assim, usando a fábrica, `for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++) { Long l = Long.valueOf(10L); }` **possivelmente** você terá apenas um objeto. (OK, creio que 10 esteja no alcance do cache permanente, então o `valueOf` garantirá 1 único objeto)

Comment: Alguns casos ele faz o flyweight, mas não na maioria então fica ruim em casos realistas. Claro que se a pessoa quer fazer errado, fará mesmo, mas muita gente deve achar que nem alocação ocorre, ainda que quem é ruim não sabe o que é alocação :)

Comment: Na própria documentação ele fala que "It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor". Isso significa que eles pelo menos tem a decência de admitir que podem ter códigos melhores.