# Como eu resolvo o problema dessa instanciação?

Tags: java

**classe Program**

```
package application;
 
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
 
import model.entities.Account;
import model.exceptions.DomainException;
 
public class Program {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter account data");
            System.out.print("Number: ");
            int number = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Holder: ");
            sc.nextLine();
            String holder = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Initial balance: ");
            double initialBalance = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Witdraw Limit: ");
            double withdrawLimit = sc.nextDouble();
 
            Account account = new Account(number, holder, initialBalance, withdrawLimit);
 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter amount for withdraw: ");
            double amount = sc.nextDouble();
            account.withdraw(amount);
 
            System.out.println("New balance: " + String.format("%.2f", account.getBalance()));
            
        } catch (DomainException e) {
            System.out.println("Witdraw Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
 
        sc.close();
    }
 
}
```

**classe Account**

```
package model.entities;
 
import model.exceptions.DomainException;
 
public class Account {
 
    private Integer number;
    private String holder;
    private Double balance;
    private Double withdrawLimit;
    
    public Account() {
    }
 
    public Account(Integer number, String holder, Double initialBalance, Double withdrawLimit) {
        this.number = number;
        this.holder = holder;
        this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
        deposit(initialBalance);
    }
 
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
 
    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
 
    public String getHolder() {
        return holder;
    }
 
    public void setHolder(String holder) {
        this.holder = holder;
    }
 
    public Double getWithdrawLimit() {
        return withdrawLimit;
    }
 
    public void setWithdrawLimit(Double withdrawLimit) {
        this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
    }
 
    public Double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    
    public void deposit(Double amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }
    
    public void withdraw(Double amount) throws DomainException{
        if (amount > balance) {
            throw new DomainException("Not enough balance");
        } else if (amount > withdrawLimit) {
            throw new DomainException("The amount exceeds withdraw limit");
        }
        balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

**classe DomainException**

```
package model.exceptions;
 
public class DomainException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    public DomainException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

> Mensagem de erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at model.entities.Account.deposit(Account.java:51)
    at model.entities.Account.<init>(Account.java:19)
    at application.Program.main(Program.java:27)
```

Não sei o porquê está dando erro, sendo que o erro é sobre o método `deposit()`. O método `deposit()` onde é usado para depositar o `balance` inicial ao invés de "setar" este `balance` direto. Se eu tiro o tipo da variável do `balance`, `deposit()` da classe `Double` para o tipo `double` dá certo.

E por quê se eu fizesse a instanciação direto:

```
    this.number = number;
            this.holder = holder;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
        }
```

Ao invés de:

```
public Account(Integer number, String holder, Double initialBalance, Double withdrawLimit) {
            this.number = number;
            this.holder = holder;
            this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
            deposit(initialBalance);
        }
```

Daria certo?

Comment: Olá @Rq, seja bem-vindo ao SOpt, vc queria dizer [instanciação](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-instanciar/)? Mas pelo que vi no seu código seu problema é mais com a chamada do que com instância.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) é uma classe e `double` é um tipo primitivo (em Java existe essa diferenciação, em outras linguagens, não necessariamente). E cada tipo possui um valor *default* que é usado quando o mesmo não é inicializado.

[Veja aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) que existe uma tabela (na seção *Default Values*) que diz que campos do tipo `double` são inicializados com zero, enquanto objetos (como o `Double`) são inicializados com `null`.

Por isso funciona quando você usa `double`, mas não com `Double`, pois este estará `null` e não será possível realizar qualquer operação com ele (por isso ocorre o [`NullPointerException`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/112052)).

Então a solução é inicializar os valores, não só para "satisfazer a burocracia da linguagem", mas também para deixar claro no código que aquilo começa com o valor zero:

```
public Account(Integer number, String holder, Double initialBalance, Double withdrawLimit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.holder = holder;
    this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
    this.balance = 0.0; // setar para zero
    deposit(initialBalance);
}
```

Se bem que neste caso não faz sentido iniciar com zero só para somar outro valor logo em seguida, então também poderia ser:

```
public Account(Integer number, String holder, Double initialBalance, Double withdrawLimit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.holder = holder;
    this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
    this.balance = initialBalance;
}
```

A menos, é claro, que o método `deposit` tenha alguma outra lógica adicional, e que seja necessária para inicializar a instância. Mas como neste caso ele só soma ao balanço atual (que por sua vez começa com zero), não sei se precisaria chamá-lo no construtor.

---

Outro ponto é verificar se você precisa mesmo usar os *wrappers*, pois os campos poderiam ser apenas:

```
private int number;
private double balance;
private double withdrawLimit;
```

Ao fazer operações (como soma e subtração) em tipos como o `Double`, é feito o [*autoboxing* e *autounboxing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), que apesar de serem "transparentes" para o programador, têm o seu custo (além de esconder "armadilhas" como essa, do `NullPointerException`). Existem também outras diferenças, que são explicadas em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/112052).

E sobre o uso de `double` para representar dinheiro, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/112052).

Answer (score 1):

Na classe Account você iniciou as seguintes variáveis, da seguinte forma:

```
private Integer number;
private String holder;
private Double balance;
private Double withdrawLimit;
```

Todas essas variáveis têm por predefinição um valor igual a null, por isso se tentar somar algo a null, vai resultar num NullPointerException.

Pode ser verificado se escrever a seguinte linha de código antes da iniciação das variáveis no Constructor da class Accounts:

```
System.out.print(this.number + " : " + this.holder + " : " + this.balance + " : " + this.withdrawLimit);
```

Para resolver poderá:

1 - Ou definir um valor para a variável logo no início:

```
private Double balance = 0.0;
```

2 - Ou altera o tipo da variável para "double", pois o tipo double tem um valor predefinido de 0.0, já o tipo "Double" tem o valor predfinido de null:

```
private double balance;
```

O mesmo se aplica por exemplo para o tipo "Integer" que tem o valor predefinido de null, mas se for do tipo "int" tem o valor predefinido de 0.

3 - Ou iniciá-la no Constructor:

```
public Account(Integer number, String holder, Double initialBalance, Double withdrawLimit) {
        this.number = number;
        this.holder = holder;
        this.balance = 0.0;
        this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
        deposit(initialBalance);
    }
```

4 - Ou ainda iniciar a variável logo com o valor inicial:

```
public Account(Integer number, String holder, Double initialBalance, Double withdrawLimit) {
        this.number = number;
        this.holder = holder;
        this.balance = initialBalance;
        this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
    }
```

Por fim, o porquê de `this.balance = initialBalance;` funcionar, é porque está a iniciar aquela variável com um valor e não a fazer uma operação com o valor dela (não dá para fazer operações com um valor nulo).

Espero que tenha respondido à pergunta e que também tenha-o ajudado, qualquer dúvida só colocar :)