# Ajuda com vetor em Java

Tags: java

Galera, gostaria de saber se tem alguma função pronta em Java ou algum jeito fácil de fazer o nome dos alunos com as maiores notas aparecerem junto, pq tá sempre pegando o ultimo aluno com a maior nota, mesmo se dois alunos tirarem a mesma nota.

```
package application;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        
        String[] nomeAlunos = new String[10];       
        nomeAlunos[0] = "Roberto";
        nomeAlunos[1] = "Carlos";
        nomeAlunos[2] = "Flavia";
        nomeAlunos[3] = "Vitor";
        nomeAlunos[4] = "Higor";
        nomeAlunos[5] = "Luiza";
        nomeAlunos[6] = "Joana";
        nomeAlunos[7] = "Isaque";       
        nomeAlunos[8] = "Gabriela"; 
        nomeAlunos[9] = "Antony";

        Double[] notaAlunos = new Double[10];
        double mediaNotas = 0, porcentAprovado, porcentReprovado;
        int[] freqAlunos = new int[10];
        int aprovados = 0, reprovados = 0, notaAprovacao = 70, freqAprovacao = 80;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < nomeAlunos.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Aluno: ");
            System.out.println(nomeAlunos[i]);
            System.out.print("Entre com a nota (0-100): ");
            notaAlunos[i] = sc.nextDouble();
            mediaNotas += notaAlunos[i];
                while(notaAlunos[i] < 0 || notaAlunos[i] > 100) {
                    System.out.print("Valor não aceito, digite novamente. ");
                    notaAlunos[i] = sc.nextDouble();
                }
            System.out.print("Entre com a frequência (0-100): ");
            freqAlunos[i] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");
                while(freqAlunos[i] < 0 || freqAlunos[i] > 100) {
                    System.out.print("Valor não aceito, digite novamente. ");
                    freqAlunos[i] = sc.nextInt();

                }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Aprovados: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < nomeAlunos.length; i++) {
            if(notaAlunos[i] >= notaAprovacao && freqAlunos[i] >= freqAprovacao) {
                aprovados += 1;
                System.out.print("Nome: " + nomeAlunos[i] + ", Nota: " + notaAlunos[i] + ", Frequência: " + freqAlunos[i] + "%");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Reprovados: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < nomeAlunos.length; i++) {
            if(notaAlunos[i] < notaAprovacao || freqAlunos[i] < freqAprovacao) {
                reprovados += 1;
                System.out.print("Nome: " + nomeAlunos[i] + ", Nota: " + notaAlunos[i] + ", Frequência: " + freqAlunos[i] + "%");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        
        Double maiorNota = notaAlunos[0], menorNota = notaAlunos[0];
        String nomeMaiorNota = "", nomeMenorNota = "";
        
        for(int i = 0; i < notaAlunos.length; i++) {
            if (notaAlunos[i] >= maiorNota) {
                maiorNota = notaAlunos[i];
                nomeMaiorNota = nomeAlunos[i];
            }
            if(notaAlunos[i] <= menorNota) {
                menorNota = notaAlunos[i];
                nomeMenorNota = nomeAlunos[i];
            }
        }
        
        
        System.out.println("Aluno com a maior nota: "); 
        System.out.println("Nome: " + nomeMaiorNota);
        System.out.println("Nota: " + maiorNota);
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Aluno com a menor nota: "); 
        System.out.println("Nome: " + nomeMenorNota);
        System.out.println("Nota: " + menorNota);
        System.out.println();
        
        porcentAprovado = aprovados * 10;
        porcentReprovado = reprovados * 10;
        System.out.println("Porcentagem de alunos aprovados: " + porcentAprovado + "%");
        System.out.println("Porcentagem de alunos reprovados: " + porcentReprovado + "%");
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Media de notas na turma: " + mediaNotas / 10);
        
        
        
                
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente, se você quer criar um array com valores fixos, pode fazer assim:

```
String[] nomeAlunos = { "Roberto", "Carlos", "Flavia", "Vitor", "Higor", "Luiza", "Joana", "Isaque", "Gabriela", "Antony" };
```

---

Se você quer todos os alunos que tiveram a maior ou menor nota, o jeito é primeiro calcular qual é a maior (e a menor) nota, e depois percorrer o array de notas e ver todos os alunos que têm esta nota.

Outro detalhe, para verificar a maior e menor nota você inicia as variáveis `maiorNota` e `menorNota` com a primeira nota, então no `for` você pode começar a partir da segunda nota:

```
double maiorNota = notaAlunos[0], menorNota = notaAlunos[0];
for (int i = 1; i < notaAlunos.length; i++) { // "i" começa em 1 (a partir do segundo elemento)
    if (notaAlunos[i] > maiorNota) {
        maiorNota = notaAlunos[i];
    }
    if (notaAlunos[i] < menorNota) {
        menorNota = notaAlunos[i];
    }
}
```

Pois se `i` começar do zero, na primeira iteração você irá comparar a primeira nota com ela mesma, o que é redundante e desnecessário.

Também mudei o tipo de `Double` (com "D" maiúsculo) para `double` (com "d" minúsculo), pois não parece haver motivo para usar os *wrappers* ([leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/112052) para mais detalhes).

Enfim, tendo a maior e menor nota, posso imprimir todos os nomes que têm estas notas:

```
System.out.println("Alunos com a maior nota (" + maiorNota +"): ");
for (int i = 0; i < notaAlunos.length; i++) {
    if (notaAlunos[i] == maiorNota) {
        System.out.println(nomeAlunos[i]);
    }
}

System.out.println("Alunos com a menor nota (" + menorNota +"): ");
for (int i = 0; i < notaAlunos.length; i++) {
    if (notaAlunos[i] == menorNota) {
        System.out.println(nomeAlunos[i]);
    }
}
```