# Retorno de números primos?

Tags: java, matemática, java-8

Estou com problema com alguns retornos informando que alguns números primos não são primos. Qual é o erro no meu código?

```
package capitulo4.laboratorio;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Laboratorio1 {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
       int valor = 1;
       
        Scanner numero = new Scanner (System.in);
    
        System.out.print ("Informe o seu numero: ");
        valor = numero.nextInt();
        
    Boolean numeroPrimo = valor%2 !=0 && valor%3 !=0 && valor%5 != 0 && 
      valor%7 !=0 && valor%11 !=0 && valor%13 !=0 && valor%17 !=0 && 
      valor%19 !=0 && valor%23 !=0; 
    
        if (valor >= 1 && valor/valor==1 && numeroPrimo == true) {
            
        System.out.println("O número informado é primo!!!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("O número informado NAO é primo.");
            }
        numero.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Números primos são números maiores que 1 (um) e que são divisíveis somente pelo número 1 (um) e por ele mesmo, ou seja se em algum caso obtivermos o resto divisão igual a zero de seus antecessores ele não será primo, por exemplo.

4 % 2 = 0 desclassificado, pensando assim você pode ter uma condição onde se o resto da divisão de um numero for zero ele não será primo.

```
class Primo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numero, contador, i;
        i = 2;
        contador = 0;
        numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Digite o numero "));
        
        while (i < numero) {
            if (numero % i == 0) contador++;
            i++;
        }
        
        if (contador > 0 || numero == 1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nao é primo " + numero);
        else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "é primo " + numero);
    }
}
```

ou seja se o `if (numeroVerificao % antecessores == 0) não é primo;`

você precisa fazer um laço de repetição pois se não vai ter que verificar cada caso por si só isso pode ser complicado, troquei a classe Scanner por JoptionPane só para ficar mais legal.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Se [pesquisar aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=n%C3%BAmero+primo), vai encontrar vários algoritmos para verificar se um número é primo.</sup>

---

O seu algoritmo só verifica se o número é divisível por alguns números primos, até o 23. Isso é **bem** limitado, pois não vai pegar vários casos. Por exemplo, o seu código diz que o número 961 é primo (mas não é, pois ele é divisível por 31).

Outra coisa esquisita é a condição `valor / valor == 1` no `if` - todo número inteiro diferente de zero dividido por ele mesmo dá 1, então para que testar isso?

Também não há motivo para usar o *wrapper* `Boolean` (com "B" maiúsculo), poderia ter usado o primitivo `boolean` (com "b" minúsculo) sem problemas (leia mais sobre isso em [É ideal usar tipos primitivos em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/112052)).

Enfim, dá para melhorar um pouco. Em vez de testar a divisão por valores fixos, basta fazer um *loop* que vai testando se o número é divisível por vários outros números. Uma implementação ingênua seria:

```
boolean numeroPrimo;
if (valor == 2) {
    numeroPrimo = true;
} else if (valor % 2 == 0) {  // se é par, mas não é 2, não é primo
    numeroPrimo = false;
} else {
    numeroPrimo = true;
    for (int i = 3; i < valor; i += 2) { // testo apenas se é divisível por ímpares
        if (valor % i == 0) {
            numeroPrimo = false;
            break; // já sei que não é primo, interrompe o for
        }
    }
}

if (numeroPrimo) {
    System.out.println("O número informado é primo!!!");
} else {
    System.out.println("O número informado NAO é primo.");
}
```

O 2 é o único número par que é primo, então eu testo esse caso especial antes. Depois, se não for 2, eu testo se é par (pois todo número par é divisível por 2 e portanto não é primo).

Se o número for ímpar, eu testo se ele é divisível por algum número ímpar (eu não preciso testar a divisão por números pares, pois se ele fosse divisível por um número par, então ele também seria par e já teria entrado no `else if (valor % 2 == 0)`).

Veja também que não preciso testar `if (numeroPrimo == true)`, é redundante e desnecessário. Variáveis booleanas podem ser testadas diretamente (apenas `if (numeroPrimo)`).

---

Dá para melhorar um pouco.

Eu não testei se o número é menor ou igual a 1, por exemplo.

E também não preciso fazer o *loop* até `valor`, eu posso ir [até a raiz quadrada do número](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811176), que já é o suficiente.

E com exceção do 2 e 3, [todos os outros números primos são da forma `6k - 1` ou `6k + 1`](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html) (ou seja, são antecessores ou sucessores de um múltiplo de 6), então eu posso fazer um *loop* que só testa esses casos:

```
boolean numeroPrimo;
if (valor <= 1) {
    numeroPrimo = false;
} else if (valor == 2 || valor == 3) {
    numeroPrimo = true;
} else if (valor % 2 == 0 || valor % 3 == 0) {
    numeroPrimo = false;
} else {
    numeroPrimo = true;
    for (int i = 5; i < Math.sqrt(valor); i += 6) {
        if (valor % i == 0 || valor % (i + 2) == 0) {
            numeroPrimo = false;
            break; // já sei que não é primo, interrompe o for
        }
    }
}
```

O *loop* começa em 5 (o menor número positivo da forma `6k - 1`), e depois eu testo se `valor` é divisível por 5 e 7 (ou seja, `6k - 1` ou `6k + 1`). Depois o *loop* prossegue de 6 em 6, pois ele testa somente os números que são antecessores ou sucessores dos múltiplos de 6. O `for` prossegue até a raiz quadrada do `valor`.