# Quando usar uma wrapper class ao invés de um tipo primitivo?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, tipagem

Quando devo utilizar uma wrapper class ao invés de tipos primitivos? Em quais circunstâncias é melhor utilizar uma wrapper class se comparado aos tipos primitivos?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3):

O principal motivo para fazer essa escolha é quando você precisa que o objeto seja acessado por uma [**referência**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) e não pelo seu valor direto, que é maior diferença entre esses dois tipos. Isso inclui a necessidade de aceitar um valor nulo nele.

Outro grande motivo é ter que **aumentar o tempo de vida do objeto**, já que os tipos por referência são armazenados no *heap* e controlados pelo Garbage Collector. Então se for usar o objeto em um outro objeto que já está no *heap* e foi criado através de *generics*, a única forma é usando a classe. A forma atual da linguagem só permite o uso de classes para isso.

Isso vai mudar. Estão prometendo há várias versões e até esta data ainda não tem, mas será possível usar tipo por valor em vários lugares, e o usuário (programador) poderá criar seus próprios tipos por valor. Quando isso estiver disponível, haverá pelo menos um motivo a menos para usar, e será mais eficiente assim.

Mas como Java ainda não terá referências, a classe ainda será necessária quando precisa desse mecanismo, pelo menos até mudarem de ideia e fazer isso melhor. Além disso precisaria ter um mecanismo quando quer que o tipo possa ser anulável e ser por valor.

Melhor nunca é, mas em alguns casos é adequado porque não tem outra forma. A incapacidade de fazer melhor torna adequado principalmente nos casos acima.

Note que é diferente dos casos que o tipo seria mais adequado ser por referência e ter tempo de vida maior. Estou mostrando apenas sobre as classes citadas na pergunta que só existem por deficiência da linguagem.

C# permite tudo e algo mais que Java sem ter essas classes.

Java queria que só tivesse classes, queriam dar um ar mais orientado a objeto. Mas ficou tudo muito lento e tiveram que criar os tais [tipos primitivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/101) (tem mais detalhes sobre o assunto, mas não tem a justificativa de escolha de uso). Curiosamente C# não se vende tanto como orientada a objeto quanto Java e é até mais. Todos os tipos são derivados de `Object`, ao contrário de Java. E é assim em Java justamente porque os tipos primitivos são gambiarra.

Pode estar pensando que eu falo que eles são gambiarra e ao mesmo tempo dizendo que eles devem ser preferidos. Sim, é isso. Na verdade deveriam ter tipos por valor que não são primitivos, ou seja, não ser uma gambiarra e sim ser um mecanismo normal da linguagem, como será no futuro, com limitações por causa da compatibilidade. E não sei como farão para que os primitivos pareçam com tipos por valor mais naturais sem ser uma exceção. Então aguarde as novidades para ver como será o novo mecanismo.

Veja também: [O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101).

Comment: Não entendi o segundo parágrafo, poderia dar um exemplo que requer um objeto? E não vou dar uma resposta, mas para mim se deve usar o tipo primitivo sempre, a não ser quando é preciso incluir em uma collection ou deseja-se permitir semântica de valor nulo. Fora isso só costumo usar métodos estáticos de conversão. No Java me parece que os wrappers não têm como tem no Ruby semânticas um pouco mais úteis como `5.minutes`, por exemplo.

Comment: Qualquer coisa que sobreviva mais que um método precisa de um tempo de vida maior. Mesmo que ainda fique só no método se for colocar um valor em um objeto de lista ou outro que seja uma classe, só pode usar outra classe (hoje).

Comment: Mas acho que aí o motivo é a inflexibilidade da collection não aceitar tipo por valor, não? Porque se for considerar tempo de vida, eu entendo que uma variável global ou de instância pode ser de tipo primitivo. Se entendi certo o problema.

Comment: Sim, por isso que precisa usar uma classe. Não existe variável global.

Comment: Ah sim, é verdade. Estou estudando muito C. :) mas ainda mantenho o ponto que uma variável de instância pode ser de tipo primitivo, não precisa ser um wrapper. O problema era esse, não? Ter que usar wrapper para um contexto maior que um método.

Comment: Em C muda tudo,, em C# também, isso só vale para o Java, é a única linguagem que tem essa gambiarra.

Comment: Alterei meu comentário.

Comment: Mas não se usar *generics*.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que estamos discutindo, eu reli seu segundo parágrafo e ainda me parece que fazer `private int valor = listaDeIntegers.get(0);` com _auto-unboxing_ contradiz ele. Não é uma variável de instância (portanto tempo de vida maior que um método) de tipo primitivo, em um objeto no heap, recebendo seu valor de um outro objeto que também está no heap?

Comment: Lei o comentário anterior.

Comment: Entendi. Com generics precisa usar tipo por referência porque o heap não guarda tipo por valor (acho que é mais ou menos isso). Achava que fosse restrição sintática do generics.